# How to do the Arabic numeric conversion to standard numeric conversion in Android?

Tags: android, localization

I am working on the localization in Android if I run the application into avd compatible to jellybean it runs fine show me the correct data so if I change the locale to Arabic the numeric which are showing also got converted into Arabic this leads a big problem  to me fetch data from server. So my overall question is

```
int i=٣٠;
```

That's in Arabic now I want it should it be like standard numeric `i=30;` even if I change the locale of the avd.